# sending image + text to whatsapp from my android device

Tags: android, whatsapp, sharing

im haveing a little problem, i have this code, so far it opens all the sharing preferences i want , when i select whatsapp or any other media to share it says that dosnt support the file , what is happening ? thanks

```
 public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {

            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                    + "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");
            PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text example");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }


    }
```

Comment: can you please post some screenshots? your question is not fully understandable!

Comment: just add that method and call it when a button is press and see what happends, is the same that happends to me @HarshitAgrawal

Comment: As far I understands your problem is that you  want to send image along with text from whatsapp?

Comment: if I got your question wrong correct me or elaborate your question to me ! I am here to help.

Comment: let me try you code as you are saying!

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal yes, i want to send the image + text